# How to create Stripe Customers based on firebase cloud function that triggers after a field is created

Tags: node.js, firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the Firestripe example for Firebase cloud functions, but I want to change up the createStripeCustomer function. Instead of firing on the creation of a new user, I want it to trigger when a field is added under that user. Let's say for example, a firstName is added to the user. At that point, I would like to create a Stripe Customer.

My database structure would look like this:

```
stripe_customers
     uid
       firstName
```

Here is what I tried, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm very new to Node.js so I'm not familiar with a lot of the syntax.

```
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.database.ref('/stripe_customers/{userId}/firstName').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  return stripe.customers.create({
    email: context.auth.email,
  }).then((customer) => {
    return admin.database().ref(`/stripe_customers/${context.params.userId}/customer_id`).set(customer.id);
  });
});
```

Comment: you don't need Cloud Functions to integrate (accept payments) with Stripe.js.

Comment: Yeah but I'm using Firebase as my backend for this project. So I figured it would be convenient to use cloud functions

Comment: @SishirMohan: I'm not very familiar with Firebase but in the snippet you shared you are using `onCreate()` event handler which should be triggered on a user record creation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#set_the_event_handler). From what I understand you would like to get notified when an existing user records is updated ? In this case you may want to look into using the `onUpdate()` event handler instead (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onUpdate).

Comment: @SishirMohan Me too, but I simply use the Stripe.js browser/web SDK to handle payment processing. You get returned a key which u store with your user info and send to trigger payout. PCI compliant.

Comment: @RonRoyston is that compatible with iOS, Swift?

Comment: @SishirMohan https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios